# create module in openerp through interface

Tags: python, xml, module, odoo

when i create a module through interface it shows me error when click on save button error in create m2o screen

ERROR ValidateError

Error occurred while validating the field(s) res_model,src_model: Invalid model name in the action definition.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error just a while ago

you need to give a proper name to your model without upper case

my example : Remise is the designation and x_remise is the module name